# Ruby send(attribute.to_sym) for Rails Method

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using Ruby 1.9.2 and need to go through all of the values for a table to make sure everything is in UTF-8 encoding.  There are a lot of columns so I was hoping to be able to use the column_names method to loop through them all and encode the values to UTF-8.  I thought this might work:

```
def self.make_utf
  for listing in Listing.all
    for column in Listing.column_names
      column_value_utf = listing.send(column.to_sym).encode('UTF-8')
      listing.send(column.to_sym) = column_value_utf
    end
    listing.save
  end

  return "Updated columns to UTF-8"

end
```

But it returns an error:

```
syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting keyword_end
        listing.send(column.to_sym) = column_value_utf
```

I can't figure out how to make this work correctly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're using [`send`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-send) wrong and you're sending the wrong symbol for what you want to do:

```
listing.send(column + '=', column_value_utf)
```

You're trying to call the `x=` method (for some `x`) with `column_value_utf` as an argument, that's what `o.x = column_value_utf` would normally do. So you need to build the right method name (just a string will do) and then send the arguments for that method in as arguments to `send`.