# Set Attribute Dynamically of Ruby Object

Tags: ruby, dynamic

How can I set an object attribute dynamically in Ruby e.g.

```
def set_property(obj, prop_name, prop_value)
    #need to do something like > obj.prop_name = prop_value 

    #we can use eval but I'll prefer a faster/cleaner alternative:
    eval "obj.#{prop_name} = #{prop_value}"
end
```

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Use [send](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/send):

```
def set_property(obj, prop_name, prop_value)
    obj.send("#{prop_name}=",prop_value)
end
```

Comment: If you are use 1.9.2 you should call public_send instead of send as send can call private methods of an object as well see [http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2006/12/the_ruby_send_h.html]

Comment: This does not work for setting a property _dynamically_.  Doing `obj.send("foo=", "bar")` will break unless the `foo=` method is already defined (by an attribute accessor or explicit method definition).  All `send` does is invoke an existing method using the specified arguments.  See:  http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-send

Comment: what if the `prop_name ` is nested key ? `foo.bar`

Comment: In a One to Many relationship, eg: Posts have many Comments, how to dynamically push the depedent instance to the independent? 

Normally, we do like this on rails: `@post.comments << @comment`, how to turn it dynamic? I know that ActiveModel automatically updates the independent when I set it on the dependent, but just for curiosity :)

Comment: wouldn't `public_send` be safer?

Answer (score 16):

`Object#instance_variable_set()` is what you are looking for, and is the cleaner version of what you wanted.

Example:

```
your_object = Object.new
your_object.instance_variable_set(:@attribute, 'value')
your_object
# => <Object:0x007fabda110408 @attribute="value">
```

Ruby documentation about [`Object#instance_variable_set`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_set)

Comment: Assuming that the OP really wants to set an instance variable rather than calling the mutator method. The question appears to be conflating the two but the example code at least is calling the mutator method.

Comment: @mu-is-too-short, Sure, but `instance_variable_set()` really sets an instance variable for a variable name that is determined at run-time. In that sense, it has the same effect as in the question, but a cleaner / clearer alternative.

Comment: Not necessarily. Directly setting an instance variable and calling a mutator method aren't always the same thing; the method can alter/check the incoming value, the method may store the value somewhere else, there might not even be an instance variable behind the mutator, ... That's all I'm saying.

Answer (score 9):

If circumstances allow for an instance method, the following is not overly offensive:

```
class P00t
  attr_reader :w00t

  def set_property(name, value)
    prop_name = "@#{name}".to_sym # you need the property name, prefixed with a '@', as a symbol
    self.instance_variable_set(prop_name, value)
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
p = P00t.new
p.set_property('w00t', 'jeremy')
```

Answer (score 5):

This answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/7466385/6094965) worked for me:

```
Object.send(attribute + '=', value)
```

`attribute` has to be a `String`. So if you are iterating trough an array of `Symbol`s (like me), you can use `to_s`.

```
Object.send(attribute.to_s + '=', value)
```